# How to convert .py file to .exe file with pyinstaller

Tags: python

I am getting a error in converting a .py file to .exe file. The exe file shall be delivered at the build folder but it was not there.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Please consider posting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the explorer, go to the .py file you want to convert to an .exe
2. Click the path and write cmd
3. In the terminal that should have popped up, type pyinstaller --onefile (and -w if your program doesn't require the terminal) filename.py
4. Hit enter and wait for it to convert
5. The .exe now should be in the dist folder, which is in the same folder your .py file is in

Good luck! :)